# Active object of the mapped array show center in scroll items react

Tags: reactjs, js-scrollintoview

I have mapped my data into **timetable** and showed them date wise (30 days) in horizontal scroll. I have set current date data as active element. But when the date is far like 22nd position and the view is only bound for 5 objects, how can I show the active object data (22nd object) in the center of my screen through smooth scroll on page load? (picture reference attached)

[image: https://i.postimg.cc/44VNBBqr/Screenshot-2.png]

**Here is my current code:**

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
const DashboardData = ({
  timetable,
  sahriToday,
  iftarToday,
  currentN,
  currentD,
  setCurrentD,
}) => {
  const handleClick = (id) => {
    setCurrentD(id);
  };


  const dateFunc = (dhur, id) => {
    let eDate = new Date(dhur);
    
    if (currentN.getDate() === eDate.getDate()) {
      setCurrentD(id);
    }
  }

  const myRef = useRef(currentD);

  useEffect(() => {
    myRef.current?.scrollIntoView ({
      behavior: "smooth",
      block: "end"
    });
  }, [currentD])
  console.log(currentD);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="mother">
        {timetable.map((timetable) => (

          <>
            <div
              className={ currentD === timetable.id ? "dayboom active" : "dayboom"  }
              onClick={() => handleClick(timetable.id)}
              ref={myRef}
            >
              <h3 className="weekday">{timetable.weekday}</h3>
              <h3 className="monthdate">{timetable.day}</h3>
              {dateFunc(timetable.edate, timetable.id)}
            </div>
          </>
        ))}
      </div>

      <div className="timeToday">
        <div className="sahriToday">
          <div>
            <h2>
              Sahri <span>Time</span>
            </h2>
            <h3>{sahriToday[0].sahri}</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="iftarToday">
          <div>
            <h2>
              Iftar <span>Time</span>
            </h2>
            <h3>{iftarToday[0].iftar}</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
export default DashboardData;
```

I have tried ***scrollIntoView()*** but that works on the full map data, not the specific one that is active.

Comment: https://i.postimg.cc/44VNBBqr/Screenshot-2.png

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to save the reference for each of the elements in the map you can try adding a ref only for the element you want the function scrollIntoView do its thing. Something like:

```
ref={currentD === timetable.id - 2  ? myRef : null}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man! it worked like charm. (Didn't need the "-2" though).

Comment: But now when I click other element to show it's data, the active element is not changing